# Use Python code inside ASP MVC 3 application

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP MVC 3 application and I have to use dmcloud API which exists only in Python or PHP or Java.

http://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/

How can I use the API inside the application even though it is not the same technology.

Comment: You really don't need python for that.  All you need is a library for encoding JSON and sending HTTP requests following the instructions here: http://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/general.html#general-api-information

Comment: You're right this way is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the client libraries. You can [use](http://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/general.html) their HTTP API [directly](http://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/cloud-api.html#cloud-api). This will be harder than using a pre-existing library, but easier than interacting with Java or Python.